# PHP 5.2 will not echo a <

Tags: php

I can not get a `<` to go into a an array or echo out. If I use `echo "From: <test@none.net>";` the result is `From:`.

If I use

```
$mailheader[] = "From: ".$current_user->display_name." <".$current_user->user_email.">\r\n"; 
$mailheader[] = "Reply-To: ".$current_user->display_name." <".$current_user->user_email.">\r\n"; 

$mailheader[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 

var_dump($mailheader);
```

The result is

```
array(3) 
{ 
    [0]=> string(37) "From: REMOVED " 
    [1]=> string(41) "Reply-To: REMOVED " 
    [2]=> string(46) "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 "
}
```

It does not show anything starting with the < I have searched but I can't see why this is. I have tried different ways including adding a \ before < but still it ignores everything past the <.

Comment: You're echoing this to the browser?  View the page source - it will be there.

Comment: `<` and `>` have special meaning in HTML output. Viewing the PHP result in the browser will make both interpreted according to their special meaning for web pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `<` and `>` have special meaning in HTML: the browser thinks that you are starting an HTML tag.

If you want to see what the real contents of the variable are, either view source or use `htmlspecialchars` on the output.

Comment: I can't believe that was all it was. Thank you.